# Meaning of だわで in this sentence

Tags: particles, particle-が, reading-comprehension

家に辿り着くまで通行人の視線を感じるわ、寒くて風邪を引きそうだわで散々だが致し方ない。

What exactly is だわで here? Google suggest it may be some kind of grammar, but it's not clear.

This is narration from context
家に辿り着くまで通行人の視線を感じるわ
Here mentions (because he was all wet) until he got home he felt the gaze of the people

寒くて風邪を引きそう the cold, look liked I was about to get a cold?

Answer (score 2):

It's [〜わ〜わで](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%8F%E3%80%9C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%A7-wa-wade-meaning/).

だ is needed to link 〜そう to わ.